# AWS SDK conflicts in Apache Flink enviromnent

Tags: aws-sdk, apache-flink

I'm trying to deploy my job to Flink environment, and always get an error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest.putCustomQueryParameter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)`

I've tried to include/exclude aws-sdk from my jar, but it didn't help.

Does anyone know how to resolve these conflicts ?

Comment: What does your job look like (in particular which sources/sinks does it use)? What flink version are you using? Can you provide the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Flink version - 1.2.1, It just reads from S3 and prints data, nothing special.
Also, I use 3rd party lib that plays with AWS. As I understand Flink has own aws-sdk and that's why we have conflicts.

Comment: How do you build your jar file ?

Comment: I'm using Maven.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920543/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-in-flink)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Flink loads many classes by default into its classpath. And your problem is just with versions conflict.

Please read the last section of this article https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html